# Rails: DELETE method not working - GET triggered

Tags: javascript, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm using scaffolding for a part of my app and now detected that the delete buttons are not working. 
**Using the following link**

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy', user_certification, :confirm => "Are you sure?", :method => :delete %>
```

When I'm using the link, I'm receiving the the `'show' action` back.

**Log**

> Started GET "/user_certifications" for ::1 at 2020-02-17 14:37:45
>   +0000 Processing by UserCertificationsController#index as HTML

I got JS loaded in the gemfile and the application.js

**GEMFILE**

```
gem 'sprockets-rails'
gem 'jquery-rails'
```

**application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require rails-ujs
```

I checked several solutions, but fail to make it work. Perhaps someone has a hint?

Comment: Run rails routes in your terminal, find a destroy route. And in the end of route add '_path'. And usually destroy routes has some record id, something like this 
user_certification_path(user)

Comment: I'm using the resources command which is adding a delete route automatically. Unfortunately this is not triggered by the user call.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue with Ruby on Rails 6.1
Later found out that the cause is due to Bootstrap lines I have put up in javascript file..
On removing it, the destroy is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems like when you add bootstrap via add yarn bootstrap jquery popper.js and then when you import bootstrap in your application.js, it seems to be conflicting with the @rails/ujs and due to which the delete functionality is disabled.

Just remove bootstrap from application.js, add a CDN to use bootstrap and the delete functionality works perfectly fine. This also resolves the problem with devise Sign Out functionality as its the same delete user session.